# Cross-validation - does training loss matter?

Tags: cross-validation

Suppose you have two models $M$ and $N$, with fixed hyperparameters.
For example $M = \operatorname{Ridge}(\lambda = 20)$ and $N = \operatorname{Lasso}(\lambda =10)$.

You estimate their training and validation losses using k-fold cross validation on a data set.

Let assume that the average validation losses are the same, but in training $M$ performs better than $N$.

In short, we have
$$\mathcal{L}_\text{training} M < \mathcal{L}_\text{training} N \le \mathcal{L}_\text{validation} M = \mathcal{L}_\text{validation} N$$

My question is, is there any reason to prefer model $N$ in this case?

$M$ has a larger train/validation gap and I feel this should be penalized. Is there any theoretical justification for this?

Comment: So you mean like they are not found by search but rather preset, right?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: I'm not sure. In practice they would be found by search. But I think the question is interesting even if they're preset.

Comment: The question is more interesting when they are preset. Because when found by search equal validation errors actually don’t mean much since they are biased and need to be adjusted (or nested CV needs to be performed) and then the decision will be easy based on the adjusted validation errors. I am trying to come up with some example to visualize under which scenario (other than pure luck) leads to lower training error when the validation errors are very close on the average.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: OK sure, they're preset